# Adjective form of "adjective"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, derivational-morphology

What is the adjective form of the word *adjective*? I wanted to say something like *adjectivial* but that's not a word.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The word you are looking for is *adjectival*.

Comment: Do you know of a website where I can look up different forms of words?

Comment: @inquisitive_web_developer: Dictionary.com often gives "related forms", and there is a list on the left where you can see the word in question in a list of its alphabetical neighbours; usually the two of them will come up with the word you need. In this case you will find "adjectival" in the alphabetical list. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/adjective